# How is Clan Total Points calculated?

Tags: clash-of-clans

As seen in a picture below, the Total Points of a clan has nothing to do with the real trophy count. So how is it calculated? And what does a high total points really tell us about a clan?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Not all trophies count toward the total points only a certain portion counts depending on the rank the player is in the clan.

```
Rank in Clan     % of Trophies that Count Towards Score
   1 - 10                       50%
  11 - 20                       25%
  21 - 30                       12%
  31 - 40                       10%
  41 - 50                        3%
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the more people you have, the higher the trophy points would be. But your clan points are pretty high for only 12 people. A high trophy point would mean the clan has a lot of good people.

Rank in Clan (Members)  % of Trophies that Count Towards Score

- **1-10** 50%
- **11-20** 25%
- **21-30** 12%
- **31-40** 10%
- **41-50** 3%.

http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Politics

Comment: Could you please cite a source, and be more specific?